# Stanford Parser: How to include the punctuations?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have used Stanford Parser to parse some of my **already tokenized and POS tagged** (by Stanford POS tagger with Gate Twitter model). But the resulting **conll 2007** formatted output does not include any punctuations. Why is that?

The command I have used:

```
java -mx16g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -sentences newline -tokenized -tagSeparator § -tokenizerFactory edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer -tokenizerMethod newCoreLabelTokenizerFactory -escaper edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBEscapingProcessor -outputFormat conll2007 edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.caseless.ser.gz ..test.tagged > ../test.conll
```

e.g.

Original tweet:

```
bbc sp says they don't understand why the tories aren't 8% ahead in the polls given the current economics stats ; bbc bias ? surely not ?
```

POS tagged tweet, used as input for Stanford parser:

```
bbc§NN sp§NN says§VBZ they§PRP don't§VBP understand§VB why§WRB the§DT tories§NNS aren't§VBZ 8%§CD ahead§RB in§IN the§DT polls§NNS given§VBN the§DT current§JJ economics§NNS stats§NNS ;§: bbc§NN bias§NN ?§. surely§RB not§RB ?§.
```

Resulting conll 2007 formatted parse:

```
1   bbc _   NN  NN  _   2   compound    _   _
2   sp  _   NN  NN  _   3   nsubj   _   _
3   says    _   VBZ VBZ _   0   root    _   _
4   they    _   PRP PRP _   5   nsubj   _   _
5   don't   _   VBP VBP _   3   ccomp   _   _
6   understand  _   VB  VB  _   5   xcomp   _   _
7   why _   WRB WRB _   10  advmod  _   _
8   the _   DT  DT  _   9   det _   _
9   tories  _   NNS NNS _   10  nsubj   _   _
10  aren't  _   VBZ VBZ _   6   ccomp   _   _
11  8%  _   CD  CD  _   12  nmod:npmod  _   _
12  ahead   _   RB  RB  _   15  advmod  _   _
13  in  _   IN  IN  _   15  case    _   _
14  the _   DT  DT  _   15  det _   _
15  polls   _   NNS NNS _   10  nmod    _   _
16  given   _   VBN VBN _   15  acl _   _
17  the _   DT  DT  _   19  det _   _
18  current _   JJ  JJ  _   19  amod    _   _
19  economics   _   NNS NNS _   16  dobj    _   _
20  stats   _   NNS NNS _   19  dep _   _
22  bbc _   NN  NN  _   23  compound    _   _
23  bias    _   NN  NN  _   20  dep _   _
25  surely  _   RB  RB  _   26  advmod  _   _
26  not _   RB  RB  _   16  neg _   _
```

As you can see, Most of the punctuations are not included in the parse. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found the answer, use

```
-outputFormatOptions includePunctuationDependencies
```

Have contacted Stanford parser and corenlp support long time ago, no response at all

Answer (score 1):

I think adding "-parse.keepPunct" to your command will fix this issue.  Please let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Says "lexparser.Options: Unknown option ignored: -parse.keepPunct".